# Catch mousedown event at jquery sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to set some css properties when I start to drag widget. Is it possible to catch mousedown event? Can't provide jsfiddle, but my efforts here:

```
    newSortableContainer.addClass('sortable_container').sortable({
            /*activate: function(event, ui) {
                if (event.ctrlKey) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    ui.item.trigger('sortSensor');
                }
                console.log(ui);
                //if (ctrl)
            } */
            /*sort: function(event, ui) {
                if (event.ctrlKey) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    ui.item.trigger('sortSensor');
                }
            },*/
            start: function(event, ui) {
                if (event.ctrlKey) {
                    //event.preventDefault();
                    ui.item.trigger('sortSensor');
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery has a mousedown event see https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

```
$( "#target" ).mousedown(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .mousedown() called." );
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I've forgotten about mousedown event in jquery :)